# Passing the selected field in a mat-select to TS

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

So I have a mat select that is populated by an array in the model ( `uniqueBusinessUnits`) and I am trying to log the selected business unit when it is changed via two way binding to `selectedUniqueBusinessUnit`. However it seems to be logging `undefined`.

**The html**

```
   <mat-form-field >
      <mat-select  placeholder="Filter By BU"
      ([value])="selectedUniqueBusinessUnit"
      (selectionChange)="uniqueBusinessUnit=$event.value;eventBusinessUnitChange('change', $event)">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let uniqueBusinessUnit of uniqueBusinessUnits" [value]="uniqueBusinessUnit.business_Unit_Code">
          {{ uniqueBusinessUnit.business_Unit_Code }}
      </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
   </mat-form-field>
```

**The ts**

```
   export class LandingPageComponent {
     uniqueBusinessUnits: Object [];
     selectedUniqueBusinessUnit: Object [];
     eventBusinessUnitChange(s, event) {
         console.log(this.selectedUniqueBusinessUnit);
     }
   }
```

Comment: Have you tried to use [(ngModel)] ?

Comment: It's `[(value)]` not `([value])`. Also `selectedUniqueBusinessUnit` should be `Object` not `Object[]` and that allocation in `selectionChange` doesn't do anything just use: `(selectionChange)="eventBusinessUnitChange('change', $event.value)"`.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your template, the problem might be :

`(selectionChange)="uniqueBusinessUnit...`

You should instead do:

`(selectionChange)="selectedUniqueBusinessUnit...`

You are trying to assing the value to the wrong attribute (oh, uniqueBusinessUnit does not even exist at that point/state of your app)! When the user clicks on one of the values, you're doing a console.log() on a selectedUniqueBusinessUnit attribute which is still undefined (because you never affected a value to it technically).

**Some suggestions**

In your component (.ts) I think selectedUniqueBusinessUnit should not be an array knowing that it's going to contain a unique value.

And if you have models (as you said), you should be using them. Why Object[ ] when you can use TheModelYouCreated[ ]?

`eventBusinessUnitChange('change', event)`: the two arguments are kind of useless here since you directly assign the $event.value in the template (.html).

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel Haughton.. try this once

```
<mat-select  placeholder="Filter By BU" [(ngModel)]="selectedUniqueBusinessUnit" (ngModelChange)="eventBusinessUnitChange('change', $event)" >
    <mat-option *ngFor="let uniqueBusinessUnit of uniqueBusinessUnits" [value]="uniqueBusinessUnit.business_Unit_Code">
          {{ uniqueBusinessUnit.business_Unit_Code }}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

use **`ngModel`** to get the selected Option. for more info about have a look here  [**`mat-select`**](https://material.angular.io/components/select/examples).

Answer (score 0):

The **HTML** must be like this Daniel:

```
<mat-form-field >
      <mat-select  placeholder="Filter By BU"
      (selectionChange)="eventBusinessUnitChange($event.value)">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let uniqueBusinessUnit of uniqueBusinessUnits" [value]="uniqueBusinessUnit.business_Unit_Code">
          {{ uniqueBusinessUnit.business_Unit_Code }}
      </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
   </mat-form-field>
```

and you will receive the value (business_Unit_Code) directly: **TS**

```
   export class LandingPageComponent {
     uniqueBusinessUnits: Object [];
     selectedUniqueBusinessUnit: Object [];
     eventBusinessUnitChange(value) {
         console.log(value);
     }
```

}